# Angular ui ui-sref links are not clickable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am practicing angular ui routes, So I wrote this simple app but ui-sref link on the page **not clickable!**.

I know this question has been asked  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983595/angular-ui-router-links-are-not-clickable), but my problem is different (I have checked my link).

html page

```
<html>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<a ui-sref="home"> home </a>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 53px">
    <ui-view ="home"> </ui-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Script

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src=“http://unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs@latest/release/angular-ui-router.min.js”></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router'])
        .config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
            .state("home",
            {
                url:"/home",
                views:{
                    'home':{template:"home.html"}
                } 
            })

            .state('otherwise'),
            {
                template:"page not availabe "
            });
        });
</script>
```

css bootstrap

Comment: You already close '<a>' with '</home>'

Comment: I corrected myself but It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router'])
        .config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
            $stateProvider
            .state("home",
            {
                url:"/home",
                views:{
                    'home':{template:"home.html"}
                } 
            })

            .state('otherwise'),
            {
                template:"page not availabe "
            });
        });
</script>
```

Try to create module and config as mentioned above. Might help!

Comment: Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: It seems your script for ui-router is not loading properly. Make sure it loads. Then there seem no issue in code.

Answer (score 0):

ui-router directive works like this:

**for views**

```
<div ui-view="home"></div>
```

**for default**

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

> Your code is fine but first check your scripts urls, be sure it worked, test it online.
>
> your ui router script already paste like this `“http://unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs@latest/release/angular-ui-router.min.js”`, remove `“url”` from first and last of your url and replace it with `"url"`.

replace `angular.js` and `ui-rourer` files as scripts to this sample

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("home", {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'home': {
        template: "home.html"
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

});
```

```html
<script src="http://localhost:50299/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:50299/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <a ui-sref="home"> home </a>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <div ui-view="home"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code it doesn't even show home as a hyperlink https://fiddle.jshell.net/2dqpqub9/2/

Comment: I checked the scripts' links but same console error

Comment: Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    at